# asp.net webapi 2 post parameter values always null(string) or 0(int)

Tags: .net-core, fetch, asp.net-core-webapi

Been through dozens of links which all say the same solution.
Create an object for the parameter in the api call. And pass that exact same object using json.

So API call is thus (which is hit):

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult SearchItems([FromBody]SearchParams searchParams)
```

Input object is defined thus:

```
public class SearchParams
  {
    public string searchWord { get; set; }

    public int anid { get; set; }
  }
```

Call is made thus:

```
let item = {
          searchWord: searchKeyword.value.trim(),
          anid: 1
      };

      const uri = "../../WebApi/SearchItems";

      fetch(uri, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(item),
        //credentials: 'include',
        mode: 'cors',
      })
```

Look at the network traffic, headers passed are thus:

```
:authority: localhost:44386
:method: POST
:path: /WebApi/SearchItems
:scheme: https
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
content-length: 32
content-type: application/json
cookie: .AspNetCore.Session=CfDJ8LGmdU3gpbZIvSkveH0x8cMT8VibUQlc07yQ8SJOo6DJkNqykRsAz2V6NVuQ5zQhzBNiHjZ2iRJc%2Fno44sQdQJhsVPnktzx8EWu%2Bptg9ONjmErDP3TZ1csme%2FAJ3H5hSgvooxH0snE00och2ov4ZldFCosHYGH6X70ESjL8PbcJg; .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Q2hy0CiNRlg=CfDJ8LGmdU3gpbZIvSkveH0x8cOOBFRZOyah2508xPXIUjTbV_weFLdM06pME-M-kc2l48FOmSym_5JS9GUHJeciQEKJI9SHBu1D-5wLcVF4de3rYsjKRsI67qGrCado7eBFDBAbeYFOLWEMbXXCQr_0vlA
origin: https://localhost:44386
referer: https://localhost:44386/lb_users/Details/11
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36
```

Payload is thus:

```
{"searchWord":"qwerty","anid":1}
```

Both my VS debugger AND Postman brings back null/0 values.

Relatively new to .net core.
So what fundamental thing am I missing here as the dozens of SO questions I've looked at all seem identical to what I've added to my solution?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
this works.

```
const uri = "../../WebApi/SearchItems";
      fetch(uri, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        },
        body: "searchWord=" + searchKeyword.value.trim() + "&anid=1",
        //credentials: 'include',
        mode: 'cors',
      })
```

So it would appear the JSON is the issue.
Have JSON objects been dropped from being passed to api calls?

Answer (score 0):

I test asp .net webapi2 and asp .net core,both can work.
Here is a demo of asp .net webapi2:

ApiController:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public string GetVal(SearchParams searchParams)
        {
            return "success";
        }
    }
    public class SearchParams
    {
        public string searchWord { get; set; }

        public int anid { get; set; }
    }
```

ajax:

```
<input id="searchWord"/>
<button onclick="sendData()">ssss</button>
<script>
    function sendData() {
        let item = {
            searchWord: $("#searchWord").val().trim(),
            anid: 1
        };

        const uri = "../api/Values";

        fetch(uri, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(item),
            //credentials: 'include',
            mode: 'cors',
        })
    }
</script>
```

headers:

```
:authority: localhost:44383
:method: POST
:path: /api/Values
:scheme: https
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7
content-length: 33
content-type: application/json
cookie: .AspNetCore.Culture=c%3Den-US%7Cuic%3Den-US; .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.I5tvYLHG_pU=CfDJ8AkZmG9N6OhEnYVb3Xy31rQgFnXqHPkWTaV4nUodZGM9SfyhvD5jztl-kzo768oHkGPUYV-bOoSNBP5OuTHO_yd08w-IxrsO39HceHJgOIqC5ePYLIxXd0w9cBzYeWEu5amihQhOqiLySw376bp9YdM
origin: https://localhost:44383
referer: https://localhost:44383/Home/Index1
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36
```

paylod:

```
{searchWord: "hghgfgf", anid: 1}
```

result:
[image]
You can also try to create a new project,and test it.